# brwoser block reuqest for CORS

Tags: php, apache, cross-browser, network-programming

i want send request from hostA(`192.168.10.16`) to hostB(publicIP:`91.241.22.2`,localIP:`192.168.10.5`)

i set Apache(91.241.22.2) with this

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

when send request to publicIP:`91.241.22.2` this worked .

but but but

when send request to localIP:`192.168.10.5` Firefox say error:Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  192.168.10.5/shemareSafhe.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

please help me:(

Answer (score 0):

Check your headers with your browser or with your shell

```
curl -i 'http://192.168.10.5/shemareSafhe.php'
curl -i 'http://91.241.22.2/shemareSafhe.php'
```

Check the difference and i prefere to set the headers only with PHP

Comment: in 192.168.10.5==> Origin is 192.168.10.16 and in 91.241.22.2 Origin is *

Comment: Then ensure that header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); was execuded and you have no apache settings which controlls that.

Comment: i set header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in first line of my code,and how can ensure apache settings control header?

Comment: Try to stop your script with a die() after your header set and check it again.
If you have the same result, then search your apache configs and htaccess files for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"